# CORS issue with Passport.authenticate() doesn't show up with Postman get request, but Nextjs is foiled querying the resource

Tags: node.js, next.js, cors

I am trying to do Google Login using  a Nextjs frontend and an Expressjs backend. [I followed this tutorial.](https://www.makeuseof.com/nodejs-google-authentication/)

I use the URL `http://localhost:5200/auth/google` and expect the same response I get using Postman:   `<title>Sign in - Google Accounts</title>` (plus 1885 lines of other stuff)

I get this error when trying to connect via Nextjs: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=email%20profile&client_id=493322088126-0kd18q0if7ccc333b3jahdh5gmgojsbgig.apps.googleusercontent.com' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5200/auth/google') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

My frontend's query: `const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5200/auth/google");`

My backend's middlewares:

```
middlewares: [
        allowAll,
        cors({ origin: "*", methods: "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT", allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Authorization" }),
        accessControlAllowOriginDev,
        bodyParser.json(),
        bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }),
        cookieParser(),
        passport.initialize(),
        (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
            console.log(req.originalUrl); //confirms the url is correct
            next();
        },
    ]
```

The route that uniquely fails: `this.router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["email", "profile"] })); // the route is correct`

I have tried:

1. [Changing the order of the middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71967555/next-js-and-express-js-give-cors-error-api-queries-only-work-at-build-time). `cors()` was last in the stack, now its first.
2. Adding `passport.initialize()` & `passport.session()`. Prior to this, both were missing. Pretty sure it's unrelated, however.
3. Sending a request to my auth controller's health check route from Nextjs and Postman. Both confirm the controller is active and running. Neither is blocked by CORS.
4. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71513911/how-to-fix-cors-error-in-my-axios-request-in-nextjs-app) which involves modifying `local.settings.json`

```
{
    "Host": {
        "CORS": "*"
    }
}
```

In summary: Postman receives the correct response from the endpoint, but Nextjs uniquely does not. Nextjs can access the healthCheck endpoint just like Postman; hence the problem is uniquely the combination of Nextjs and Passport. I have no idea what's wrong.

edit: Can someone tell me? If I had CORS configured correctly, *every* request would come back with "Allow-access-control-origin: *" on the headers, right? My Postman response headers do say `X-Powered-By: Express  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

edit2: [I'm hot on the trail of a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72029668/how-to-fix-cors-policy-with-passport-twitch-new). [This looks similar](https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2/issues/43)

Answer (score 0):

Solution found

[[Passportjs][Angular5] No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50317575/passportjsangular5-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the)

By user "SuperUser Sudo":

"""

You can simply write in your html template

`<a href="http://localhost:3000/login/google">Google</a>`

and on the backend you just need to have this

`app.get('/login/google',  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile','email']}) );`

"""